# How do I update Oracle Java (JDK and JRE)

Tags: java, software-installation, oracle

Recently, I've installed JDK 7 from the Oracle site, using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/81136).

Now, I'm wondering what is the correct method to update it (or, better, to keep up-to-date automatically)? For instance, there were some security issues fixed few days ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Comment: @PawełPrażak err... Install != update ;)

Comment: @Briam works for update

Comment: @PawełPrażak "Now, I'm wondering what is the correct method to update it (or, better, to keep **up-to-date automatically**)?"

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Now, you can use the [Linux Uprising Java PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java), so you get [updates automatically](https://askubuntu.com/a/99522/23878) through the package manager. If you need the latest Oracle [Java 12](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-12-jdk-12-in.html), you install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java12-installer
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

**Old solution - DISCONTINUED- does not work anymore**

You can use the [WebUpd8 Java PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java), so you get [updates automatically](https://askubuntu.com/a/99522/23878) through the package manager. If you need the latest Oracle [Java 8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/oracle-java-8-stable-released-install.html), you install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

- [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

If you need the latest Oracle Java 6 (Outdated version), you install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

If you need the latest Oracle Java 7 (Outdated version), you install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

If you want test Oracle [Java 9](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html) early access builds, you can install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

To switch between different Java versions, you could use the following terminal command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

**Source:**

- [Web Upd8: Install Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu via PPA Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)
- [Web Upd8: Oracle Releases Critical Security Update For Java 7 (7U13) And Java 6 (6U39), PPA Updated](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/oracle-releases-critical-update-for.html)
- [Web Upd8: Install Oracle Java 8 In Ubuntu Via PPA [JDK8]](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)
- [Web Upd8: Oracle Java 8 (Stable) Released, Install it In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/oracle-java-8-stable-released-install.html)
- [Web Upd8: Install Oracle Java 9 In Ubuntu, Linux Mint Or Debian Via PPA Repository [JDK9]](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html)

Comment: I can't downvote rightnow but I criticize this. You told an entirely new way of installation instead of answering upon what OP asked for. May be didn't choose `webupd8` installation because of some valid reasons. Like in my case I didn't go for it as it didn't provided just JRE & I didn't required the entire JDK package. I think you must provide an answer to the OP's situation besides suggesting this alternate way.

Comment: Reread the OP, user01:  "Recently, I've installed JDK 7 from the Oracle site,"  

The question is therefore:  "How can I keep my JDK installations up to date automatically?"

Comment: This is very good answer, indeed. If there were another one, explaining how to do it without repositories, I'd probably upvoted it too.

Comment: Is there a way to run `update-alternatives` when you don't have interactive access? Like during ansible provisioning?

Comment: I get an error: **sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found**