# Java compiler cannot be found

Tags: command-line, java, jdk

I installed `j2ee` with `j2sdk` on my Ubuntu 12.04 computer. It is installed at `/mallika/glassfish3/jdk7/`.

I am able to run any of my Java programs in Netbeans using this JDK.

Since Netbeans 7 does not support RMI programs, I tried to compile these from command prompt, but then I get the following error on giving the following command:

```
..~$ javac rmiclient/LoginGUI.java 
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:  
 * default-jdk  
 * ecj  
 * gcj-4.6-jdk  
 * openjdk-6-jdk  
 * gcj-4.5-jdk  
 * openjdk-7-jdk  
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

My system now has both OpenJDK (I do not know where) and JDK 7 as I mentioned above.   How do I set path or something so that I can compile Java sources from command prompt.

Comment: Which Java versions did you installed through the package-management-system?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the OpenJDK versions (`openjdk-6-jdk` or `openjdk-7-jdk`):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

If you need the Oracle Java JDK have a look at:

- [How do I update Oracle Java 7 (JDK and JRE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183867/how-do-i-update-oracle-java-7-jdk-and-jre/183868#183868)